# Strings passed to a function not altered by it in the D Language

Tags: d

I am a long time C programmer. I have heard about D and have decided to learn it.  I like the capabilities it seems to offer. I have come across an issue that has me stumped.  I have looked online and haven't found much of an answer.  I am trying to pass strings through a function:

```
module main;

import std.stdio;
import std.string;

int foobar(string s1, string s2)
{
    string t1="Hello";
    string t2="there";
    writeln("t1 = ",t1, " t2 = ", t2);
    s1=t1;
    s2=t2;
   writeln("s1 = ",s1," s2 = ",s2);
   return 0;
}

int main(string[] args)
{
    string a1;
    string a2;
    foobar(a1, a2);
    writeln("a1 = ",a1," a2 = ",a2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is as follow:

```
t1 = Hello t2 = there
s1 = Hello s2 = there
a1 =  a2 =
```

I have tried to search online for an answer can I can't find one.  I suspect that I am just not asking the right question.  I know I can do this using char strings, but I am trying to do this the "D way".  Will somebody point me to a reference that can help with this or tell me the question to ask?

If this has been answered before, I apologize.  I probably didn't ask the correct question.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Michael

Comment: I guess strings in D are passed by value, same as `int`s and other primitive types, unless explicitly specified otherwise. That means they (and probably a lot of other types) behave exactly like embedded types. On the contrary, in C you simply cannot "pass by value" an array - you have to stick with pointers and "pass by reference".

Comment: You should read this introduction to D: http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/index.html

Comment: If you were writing a C program: `void test(const char* a) { a = "something"; } int main() { const char* b = "hey"; test(b); }` would you expect b == "something" after calling test? D does it (almost) the same way: it just also passes a hidden `length` with the pointer and calls that a `string`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `ref` to your parameters (e.g., `int foobar(ref string s1, ref string s2)`). A string is just regular slice to immutable chars so it gets passed around by value. If you want to change the slices they needs to be passed by reference.

Comment: ref was the perfect answer.  Thank you very much.  I knew there had to be a way to do this.